# Am I my own ally?

Tags: legend

If I use an ability that targets all allies (such as the Sage's Healing Burst from the Force of Will track), am I included? If I use an ability that targets some specific number of allies (such as the Sage's Stitch in Time ability, also from the Force of Will track), can I choose myself as one of the allies?

I did see a few examples that makes me think I *do* count as my own ally, but I'm used to 4e where you *don't* count as your own ally, and I didn't see a definite rule clarifying the matter (though I certainly could have missed it).

From the Ranger's Professional Soldier track, p72 (*emphasis mine*):

> **7<sup>th</sup> Circle - The Sound of Cannon:** ... You gain a +6 bonus to your initiative, and all allies gain a +4 bonus to initiative, bringing *your* total bonus to +10.

Some feats, from p164 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Recon:** At the beginning of each [Encounter], before the first [Round], each ally may make a 5 ft step, even if that ally is surprised. At 6th level, this increases to two 5 ft steps *for you only*.
>
> **Reprisal:** You are healed twice your character level whenever an ally *other than you* is dropped below half their maximum hit points. ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You are always your own ally**

From the glossary, page 212 (*emphasis added*):

> Ally refers to any creature in an [Encounter] that
>   you choose to regard as friendly for the purpose of
>   any particular action or ability. You cannot treat a
>   creature as an ally unless they allow you to do so.
>   *You are always your own ally.* You can assign this
>   term as you wish, though a creature can never be
>   treated as both an ally and an opponent for purposes
>   of a single instance of the same effect.

However, some abilities specify that they only affect, or are only triggered by, *other* allies - such as the *Reprisal* ability you quoted above.