# Warforged resolve with reparation apparatus

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm working on an artificer build and I was wondering whether the [Reparation Apparatus](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2168) would work when an Warforged uses his racial power [Warforged Resolve](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2485).

I know he doesn't get the 2d6 Hit points because he doesn't spent an surge. But will he get the 2d6 bonus Temp Hit points?

**Bonus question:**
What happens when an Warforged uses his 2nd wind while he has an Reparation Apparatus?
Does he get both the 2d6 Hit points and the 2d6 Temp Hit points or are both powers not working together with the Reparation Apparatus the way I am imagining it.

Reparation Apparatus:

> When you use a power that allows a construct to spend a healing surge to regain hit points, that creature regains an additional 2d6 hit points. When you use an encounter power or a daily power to grant temporary hit points to a construct ally, that creature gains an additional 2d6 temporary hit points.

Warforged Resolve

> Effect: You gain a number of temporary hit points equal to 3 + one-half your level and can make a saving throw against one effect on you that deals ongoing damage. If you are bloodied, you also regain hit points equal to 3 + one-half your level.

Comment: You are linking to the Compendium, which means the question can't be answered except by someone who has access to it. Maybe summarize what the item does in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Here's the problem, the second half of Reparation Apparatus only benefits *allies you heal* and does *not* apply to self healing which is what Warforged Resolve is.

Second Wind on the other hand is a power that allows you to spend a healing surge and thus will benefit from Reparation Apparatus's first effect (which does *not* specify allies, just constructs).

Comment: I thought that you always counted as an ally for yourself.
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/am-i-my-own-ally

Comment: @Mouhgouda powers that target allies do not target you unless they specify. The question you link to is for Legend, not D&D 4e.

Comment: darf! You're right, never mind me...